# I'm building a WordPress theme and noticed that the 404 page template runs along with the corresponding templates for each page. Any idea why?

Tags: page-template, template-hierarchy

```
function debug($message){

   error_log($message, 3, get_template_directory() . '/debug.log');

}
```

I added the above function to each of the templates.

For example, **front-page.php** includes a line that goes like this: `debug("front-page.php \n");`

I use `tail -f debug.log` in the terminal to determine which templates are being used by a particular page.
Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: how are you testing that these log lines are coming from the same page request? This could be as trivial as an image tag with a broken `src="/"` in your 404 template

Comment: I just added the debug function to each template with the corresponding name. When I refresh the page (for example, front page), the log in the terminal shows both front-page and 404, indicating that the page is using both the templates.

Comment: I don't think that's enough, at a minimum you should include the current URL in the message, what you're describing is not how WordPress templating works and you should be seeing 2 pages one above the other, or, one inside the other, but that's not what you described. Instead it's more likely that one page triggers a second request which is why you're seeing 2 templates loaded, and the URL will help inform what's doing that

Comment: It could be as simple as a broken asset URL for a CSS file etc

Comment: You were right. Thank you for helping me find the bug. It was indeed a broken link to a CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following function to retrieve the URLs of each page.

```
  function template_debug($filename = null) {
        $url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        debug("Called from: $filename using URL $url \n");
    }
```

Then I inspected the front page which triggered the 404 template along with the front-page template. The **Network Monitor** tab showed the error, which was an incorrect folder name included in the CSS file.

After making the necessary changes, the 404 template isn't being triggered anymore.